# postgress db dump from aws-rds instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-rds

I am trying to export the db dump from postgress aws-rds instance through the ubunutu terminal using below command but its throwing error.

```
pg_dump -h XX.XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 -Fc -o -U XXUser XXDbname > output.dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "XXDbname" failed: could not translate host name "XX.XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432" to address: Name or service not known
```

I tried to find the ip address too using sql query as 
select inet_server_addr()

and when I run the pg_dump command using this ip. Its throwing connection timeout. 
Please suggest is there a way to export the dump from a rds-postgress instance while having only the db user access.

> > Update - tried with -p port too. But still same error
> >
> > pg_dump -h XX.31.X.X -p 5432 -Fc -o -U XXuser XXdb > XXdump.dump
> >
> > pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "XXdb" failed: could
> >     not connect to server: Connection timed out     Is the server running on
> >     host "XX.31.X.X" and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the port with the host name, but specify it with the `-p` option.

So instead of

```
-h XX.XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

use

```
-h XX.XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432
```

Comment: No luck still error.
pg_dump -h 172.31.X.X -p 5432 -Fc -o -U XXuser XXdb > XXdump.dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "XXdb" failed: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
 Is the server running on host "172.31.X.X" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Options. 1) a firewall is blocking the connection 2) the database is not started 3) the database is not listening on the public interface on port 5432